# How to use jQuery to style active link list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am using jQuery to check if the browser URL matches the URL in my link href, the issue is after my check I am trying to set the li tag class that the link matches to be "active", but this code below is setting the link tag as active not the li tag

```
    $(function(){
        var current = location.pathname;
        $('#nav li a').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            // if the current path is like this link, make it active
            if($this.attr('href') === current){
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Since you are not showing code (due to highlevel trademark and copyright reasons) can you show `console.log(current);` and `console.log($this);`.? ... That is, even if you think this is an attitude it is not, show your code.

Comment: I suggest using a more descriptive title when asking questions. For a moment I thought this was a question like "When to use jQuery?". Almost ended up closing the question for being primarily opinion based..

Comment: Your "this" refers to the a href instead of the li. Look for all attr hrefs current first, then style each's parent li.

Comment: @icecub np I edited the question, re read it and changed my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the *a* element not the *li* you are thinking which is actually the parent of the current element (*a*).

You have to target the [**`parent()`**](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$this.parent().addClass('active');
```

**OR:** Using [**`.closest()`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$this.closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

## Hello

You can try to use this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".nav li").click(function () {
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
.headerTopMenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.headerTopMenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.headerTopMenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    padding: 0;
}
.headerTopMenu li.active a, .headerTopMenu li a:hover {
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headerTopMenu">
  <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#blogs">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```